# Ethernet wall socket not connecting

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, cat5e

I have an ethernet wall socket wired (the relevant one is #16):

[image]

...and my ethernet wall socket (the right side is ethernet, the left is a phone line):

[image]

- When I connect via ethernet to my router, I get an internet connection.
- When I connect via ethernet to the switch port 16, I get an internet connection. This is where the ethernet wall socket is wired to.
- I do not get any internet connection on my Mac when connecting via ethernet to the above wall socket.

From my limited knowledge of what I've read/watched online, it seems to be wired correctly as they both use 'B'.

Is there anything obviously wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

**Background**

My parents had a contractor wire ethernet wall sockets to every room over 7 years ago. They did not check if all of them were working. I am only now checking them - a few work and connect, but most do not. The above photos are an example of one socket that does not connect.

Comment: Please include a clear shot of 16 White/Orange and White/Green, 14 is wired incorrectly, use an RJ45 Network Cable Tester with Ground Test to identify where the insulation has not been adequately displaced to allow contact, or find cores have been inadvertantly crossed

Comment: Thanks for your help. I bought a tester and no lights show at all. The cable must be cut somewhere as another user mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a few work and connect, but most do not" -- and they all are wired the same.

So, I imagine things are pretty clear - some wires aren't plugged all the way in. Maybe they oxidised. To check which, you need a wire tester.

The simplest test is to use a "pen" tester. This is a small emitter that clamps on a wire (you'll use a male RJ45 connector, clamping all the wires in turn), plus a pen sensor that beeps when it detects the signal of the emitter, conducted by the wire.

Connect the emitter to the connector (e.g. to the orange wire) and the connector to one end, if there's no buzz you'll know there's a bad contact at the emitter end on the orange wire. Swap emitter and sensor to check the other end of the wire.

Then you'll have to pull the wires out, trim, and re-fit back in. With the appropriate tools, it's a matter of one hour at the most.

There are several ways of checking for wire continuity; if at least two wires, or one wire and ground, are well connected, a clever tester can locate all breakages on both ends of eight wires in a single sitting. Most testers aren't that clever. These two are the manual method with the beeper-finder, and a common check using short circuits (in green) at one end. As you can see, the second method here can only tell you that a given pair is broken, but not where the breakage is.

[image]

This is probably more suited to Electrical Engineering though.

Comment: Thank your for your detailed explanation. I used an Ethernet tester and the lights do not blink at all when connecting both ends. It blinks for other working sockets. Does this mean the whole cable is not working?

Comment: @WunDaii probably your tester tests the "whole" connection - four wires minimum at a time. So it can only say "the cable works" / "the cable does not work". Such testers usually are made by shorting the pairs at one end and measuring resistance at the other end. They do work, but are useless to pinpoint the problem more precisely, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I bought a better tester and found that two rooms are wired to each other, rather than the patch panel! The electrician must have mis-wired it. I posted another question related this issue here: https://superuser.com/questions/1633918/ethernet-cable-tester-only-blinks-on-4-and-5-incorrect-order

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with ethernet punch-down connectors is it's really, really hard to tell by eye if they're connecting well.

They're all in the right place by the looks of it, but the actual electrical connections may not be perfect. Ethernet will work at a reduced speed if 'not all' the connections are perfect, but you can't tell by sight which might be.

Your two immediate courses of action are:-

1. Buy a punch-down tool [anything from a couple of quid/bucks/shekels for a disposable to $£€ 25 for a proper one]. Pull each of the wires out one at a time from the 'loose' end with needle-nose pliers & punch them down again just half an inch further up.
2. Buy an ethernet cable tester - which will basically tell you which need to be punched down again - see 1.

The other slight problem [which may or may not be part of the issue] is that the original installers have unwound the pairs. There's a really good reason ethernet cable is called 'twisted pair' & that's because each pair really should remain twisted together  to as close as possible before the connector. You could re-twist them as you punch them in again, just to be certain.

Comment: Thank your for your detailed explanation. I used an Ethernet tester and the lights do not blink at all when connecting both ends. It blinks for other working sockets. Does this mean the whole cable is not working?

Comment: If you get no lights at all, there's the possibility the cable's been cut somewhere you can't see [or that's not the cable you think it is]. I wouldn't like to try track that down if it runs out of sight for any great length.

Comment: It runs right through the house walls, so I won’t be able to track it unfortunately. That’s a shame! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I bought a better tester and found that two rooms are wired to each other, rather than the patch panel! The electrician must have mis-wired it. I posted another question related this issue here: https://superuser.com/questions/1633918/ethernet-cable-tester-only-blinks-on-4-and-5-incorrect-order I marked the first answer as the accepted answer (answered just 4 mins before), but yours definitely helped me as well!